# Full RAM usage when I add limit to insert select query

Tags: postgresql

It works great when I do :

```
INSERT INTO gram (t1_id, t1_lower, t1_pos, t1_lemma, t2_lower, t2_pos, t2_lemma, t3_lower, t3_pos, t3_lemma, t4_lower, t4_pos, t4_lemma, lang )
                (SELECT 
                    t1.id as t1_id,
                    t1.lower as t1_lower,
                    t1.pos as t1_pos,
                    t1.lemma as t1_lemma,
                    t2.lower as t2_lower,
                    t2.pos as t2_pos,
                    t2.lemma as t2_lemma,
                    t3.lower as t3_lower,
                    t3.pos as t3_pos,
                    t3.lemma as t3_lemma,
                    t4.lower as t4_lower,
                    t4.pos as t4_pos,
                    t4.lemma as t4_lemma,
                    'fr' as lang
                FROM token t1
                LEFT JOIN token t2 ON t1.next_id = t2.id
                LEFT JOIN token t3 ON t2.next_id = t3.id
                LEFT JOIN token t4 ON t3.next_id = t4.id
                WHERE t1.lang = 'fr');
```

Strangely, when I add `limit 500000` to the select query, ram usage goes to 100% and it exit postgres and passe to recovery mode :

```
INSERT INTO gram (t1_id, t1_lower, t1_pos, t1_lemma, t2_lower, t2_pos, t2_lemma, t3_lower, t3_pos, t3_lemma, t4_lower, t4_pos, t4_lemma, lang )
                (SELECT 
                    t1.id as t1_id,
                    t1.lower as t1_lower,
                    t1.pos as t1_pos,
                    t1.lemma as t1_lemma,
                    t2.lower as t2_lower,
                    t2.pos as t2_pos,
                    t2.lemma as t2_lemma,
                    t3.lower as t3_lower,
                    t3.pos as t3_pos,
                    t3.lemma as t3_lemma,
                    t4.lower as t4_lower,
                    t4.pos as t4_pos,
                    t4.lemma as t4_lemma,
                    'fr' as lang
                FROM token t1
                LEFT JOIN token t2 ON t1.next_id = t2.id
                LEFT JOIN token t3 ON t2.next_id = t3.id
                LEFT JOIN token t4 ON t3.next_id = t4.id
                WHERE t1.lang = 'fr' limit 500000);
```

Any possible explanation ?

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` will give you the explanation.

Comment: @mustaccio here is the result, I cannot add analyse for the 2nd because it crashes the server https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nvdhahf6Igg04ruKXQ-Mgh_EmMXgs9h3/view Any explanation ?

Comment: Your 2nd plan makes no sense for the indicated query.  That query is going to generate a plan with a LIMIT node, but your plan does not show one.

Comment: Look in the database's log file to see what caused it to crash.  If it has no explanation other than a signal 9, then look in the system's log file to see if it invoked the OOM killer.

Comment: Please show text as text, rather than (or at least in addition to) images of text.

Comment: And, obviously, *always* the version of Postgres in use.